# What is the difference between 할래요 and 하고 싶어요?

Tags: grammar, verb-endings, auxiliaries

Or more specifically, the difference between

- V + (으)ㄹ래요
- V + 고 싶어요

They both seem to express intention in doing something, equivalent to "I want to do" in English. What is the difference?

Comment: V + 고 싶어요 implies something like "I want to do";; V + (으)ㄹ래요 implies something like "Let's do"

Comment: @user17915 Can you at least look up the words in the dictionary before making a comment? Where did you find this *V + (으)ㄹ래요 implies something like "Let's do"*? Can you write an example sentence?

Comment: @rath sorry it might be wrong that's why it's just a comment and not an answer. You are more than welcome to provide a correction if it is.

Comment: @user17915 If you are not sure, you don't have to make a comment. That comment is misleading and not constructive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think -ㄹ래요 is more like "I'm going to...": you announce your *intention* to do something, implying that you will do it.  E.g.,

> (a) (식당에서) 비빔밥 먹을래요. = I'll choose *bibimbap*.
>
> (b) 비빔밥 먹고 싶어요. = I want to eat *bibimbap*.

In a dialogue, saying (b) would mean you're waiting for the other person's response.  So, the sentence can be used when it is uncertain whether you would eat bibimbap after all: the other person might suggest to go to a Chinese restaurant instead.

In case (a), you are ordering bibimbap, so it's clear that you will receive bibimbap by saying these words.  So, in the context of ordering food, (a) is more natural.

Just like "I'm going to...", -ㄹ래요 does not always require immediate action.  You could add conditions:

> 비가 계속 오면 집에 갈래요. = If it keeps raining, I'm going home.
>
> 배고플 때 먹을래요. = I'm gonna eat it when I get hungry.
>
> 통일이 되면 평양에 가볼래요. = If Korea is unified, I'll visit Pyongyang.

Comment: I generally agree with your answer, but you should explain that they basically have the same meaning and the difference is very subtle. For example,  you can use "비가 계속 오면 집에 가고 싶어요", "배고플 때 먹고 싶어요", and "통일이 되면 평양에 가고 싶어요." The first one sounds a little weird, and I don't see any big difference in the last two sentences. -ㄹ래요 expresses more willingness and intention than -고 싶어요.